# Open Source Text Image such as Captcha?

Tags: captcha, bots

I am hoping someone here might know a good open source solution for the prevention of bots?

Our programmer prefers not to work with Captcha and would like the most control possible over it.

Could someone recommend please some good open source solutions and/or a good approach at protecting ourselves from bots?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You dont' mention your programming language, but for Java have a look a JCaptcha:

http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/